# How to show total weight and volume in OpenCart 2.0 checkout cart?

Tags: php, opencart2.x

The default view cart page shows the total product weight. How can I show total volume as well? Each product/item has volume size (LxWxH). There is a cart file is in catalog/view/theme/default/template/checkout/cart.tpl. Is this where I can modify?

Thanks for any help
[image: Cart Screen]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must add Volume in this file:

```
upload/system/library/cart/cart.php
```

https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/248bf46d897385bd6de70404fa37d3a6a2857453/upload/system/library/cart/cart.php

Answer (score 0):

In the cart.php file, I add a line
$this->volume = $registry->get('length') * $registry->get('width') * $registry->get('height');
to see if it give me the volume variable to put in the cart.tpl file to show total volume and get this error.
Object of class Cart\Length could not be converted to int in /homepages/26/d186500961/htdocs/cart/system/library/cart/cart.php on line 13.
How to fix it?  Do you see where else in the cart.php that I need to modify?
[image]

Thanks for the help.